# Difference between marketing app in salesforce developer account and salesforce marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am new to salesforce community, please explain to me what is the difference between marketing app in salesforce developer account and salesforce marketing cloud.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce "*Marketing app*" is just a predefined set of tabs on the UI of Salesforce.

Marketing Cloud is a separate platform entirely, like Pardot or Marketo.